# função getBy do JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

eu tenho uma classe chamada pessoa

```
public class Pessoa{
   private Long id;
   private String nome;
   private String email;

   //construtores e getters e setters
}
```

no JpaRepository tem uma função chamada `getBy()` .
como posso usar essa função para pegar uma pessoa por exemplo pelo email? pelo id sei como é.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, JpaRepository precisa de uma Entity, não sei se é o caso, mas você nos mostrou um simples POJO

Enfim... Tendo uma entity você pode sim construir querys a partir de nomes de métodos, basta adiciona-los a sua interface JpaRepository

DOC do Spring Data:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords

Guia um pouco mais mastigado:
https://www.javaguides.net/2018/11/spring-data-jpa-query-creation-from-method-names.html

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -4):

Crie um metodo chamado findByOneEmail(String email) na classe Repositorio que será utilizada.

```java
interface PessoaRepository implements JpaRepository<String, Long> {
 Pessoa findByOneEmail(String email);
}
```